# Expected value log-normal variable

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose $X_t$ and $Y_t$ both have standard normal distributions with mean zero and variance 1. 
What is the $E_t[e^{aX_t + bY_t^2}]$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants?

It should be something like:

$E_t[e^{aX_t + bY_t^2}]=e^{0.5a^2 + 2*b^2 + ab \times cov(X_t, Y_t^2)}$

Am I right? If so, how to compute the last covariance knowing $Cov_t(X_t, Y_t) = c$, where $c% is a constant.

Comment: Assuming that $X_t$ and $Y_t$ have a joint normal distribution, the random variables $X_t-cY_t$ and $Y_t$ are uncorrelated, hence independent. Therefore $E[e^{aX_t+bY_t^2}]=E[e^{aX_t-acY_t}]
\cdot E[e^{bY_t^2+acY_t}]$. Compute $E[e^{aX_t-acY_t}]$ by using the fact that $X_t-cY_t$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1-c^2$. Compute $E[e^{bY_t^2+acY_t}]$ by completing the square in the exponent of the integral $\int_{\Bbb R}e^{by^2+acy}{e^{-y^2/2}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dy$. This integral will converge only for $1-2b>0$.

Comment: The variables $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are not independent

Comment: Right. I was working under the assumption that they had a bivariate normal distribution with standard normal marginals and covariance equal to $c$. In this case $X_t-cY_t$ and $Y_y$ *are* independent.

Comment: Right. Could you please be more explicit about what is the solution of this 
$E_t[e^{aX_t + bY_t^2}]$?